# Plotting multiple set of data in pcolor plot python

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.4

I have data sets like (x,y,(z1,z2,z3..)). I am trying

```
plt.pcolor(x,y,z1)
plt.pcolor(x,y,z2)
plt.pcolor(x,y,z3)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This is showing only the pcolor plot of the last data set. How can I plot all in same plot and same colorbar scale?

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `subplots`, and make sure all the images with the same intensity scale (use the same `vmin` and `vmax` arguments of `pcolor()` for all your images). Below is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dx, dy = 0.15, 0.05

y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-3, 3 + dy, dy),
                slice(-3, 3 + dx, dx)]
z = (1 - x / 2. + x ** 5 + y ** 3) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)
z1 = z[:-1, :-1]
z2 = z[:-1, :-1]
z3 = z[:-1, :-1]
z_min, z_max = -np.abs(z).max(), np.abs(z).max() 

data = [[x,y,z1],[x,y,z2],[x,y,z3]]

# Plot each slice as an independent subplot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
for dat, ax in zip(data, axes.flat):
    # The vmin and vmax arguments specify the color limits
    pc = ax.pcolor(dat[0],dat[1],dat[2], vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
# Make an axis for the colorbar on the right side
cax = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
fig.colorbar(pc, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

It will show like this:
[image]

Comment: What I want is putting all these in same plot. Consider a typical picture of light beam incident, reflected and transmitted. I have 3 sets of z-coordinates describing incident reflected and transmitted wave amplitudes. I want to put them together so they look like real light beam being reflected and transmitted.